# VBA Calling odd behaviour

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the code below to create checkboxes. It's assigned to a button and works perfectly every time (and has done for weeks). It counts how many rows are in use, then adds boxes in columns A and P for each in use row.

However, when calling this module from another macro, it fails. The macro fires but it places checkboxes in the wrong positions.

I'm calling it as the last line of code in my module, so there is nothing after it that could alter it. The checkbox macro as a standalone still works, and I'm actually using it to correct the errors.

Interestingly, if I simply paste the code into my module instead of calling it, it **still** doesn't work correctly.

The checkboxes are also linked correctly to the cells I intended, it's just the actual visual positioning of the box that is not correct. The boxes that should land in column A consistently land 7 rows too high, and the boxes for column P consistently land 7 rows too high and in column K.

I have no idea why calling the module or adding the code into a new one is causing the effects to change. Any suggestions?

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Fix_Boxes_PC()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim worked_range As Range, cell As Range, handover_range As Range
    Dim lrow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Tracker")

    On Error Resume Next

    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Delete

    lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set worked_range = Range("A12:A" & lrow)
    Set handover_range = Range("P12:P" & lrow)

    For Each cell In worked_range
        Set cb = ws.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, 95, 6)    

        With cb
            .Caption = ""
            .LinkedCell = cell.Address
        End With
    Next

    For Each cell In handover_range
        Set cb = ws.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, 95, 6)

        With cb
            .Caption = ""
            .LinkedCell = cell.Address
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So where are you adding checkboxes, to `ActiveSheet` or to `ws`?

Comment: Assuming you want to add the checkboxes on worksheet `Tracker` (and not the active sheet), you have to use `Set worked_range = ws.Range("A12:A" & lrow)`. And use `ws.CheckBoxes.Delete`. You shouldn't rely on `ActiveSheet` in your code.

Comment: I've rewritten from scratch making sure I used the correct variables and it appears to be working, thanks.